# How to make div inside another div visible

Tags: css

I want to make a child div inside parents div visible if I give the child div margin-top negative value.

I have tried with position:relative and z-index, but it doesn't seems work.

Here are my code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="main-site">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="overlap top-border-radius">
      <div id="facultylist">
        <h1>Affordable Professional Web Design</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eu luctus ipsum, rhoncus semper magna. Nulla nec magna sit amet sem interdum condimentum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#facultylist {
  position: relative;
}
.main-site {
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlap {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.top-border-radius {
  border-top: #006af4 3px solid;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to remove `overflow: hidden` on `.container`:

```css
#facultylist {
  position: relative;
}

.main-site {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

.overlap {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.top-border-radius {
  border-top: #006af4 3px solid;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-site">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="overlap top-border-radius">
      <div id="facultylist">
        <h1>Affordable Professional Web Design</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eu luctus ipsum, rhoncus semper magna. Nulla nec magna sit amet sem interdum condimentum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```